# Not able to upload file using curl in PHP + Windows | but working in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, curl

The following piece of code, uploads the files fine on Ubuntu/Mac but uploads this kind of thing, when I try to run this code on Windows.

--------------------------56a03f9b502371ba
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

@C:\Users\Eckovation\Desktop\test.archive
--------------------------56a03f9b502371ba--

The code that I used is as follows,

```
            $path="C:\\Users\\AK\\Desktop\\test.archive";
            $header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
            $fields = array('file' => '@' . "$path");

            $resource = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
            curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
            curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            $result = json_decode(curl_exec($resource));
            curl_close($resource);

            return $result;
```

In here, the URL in question is a signed url of AWS S3 object.
The url has absolutely no problems, as same code works fine on Ubuntu/Mac.

Comment: Any error messages? Do you have cURL installed on Windows?

Comment: No error messages. yes cURL installed. I am on XAMPP installation for windows.